# How can I separate this Core Data?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, core-data

I have the following model:

[image]

On each button click new values would get saved such as:

```
    for member in self.markersArray {
        var newCoordinate = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Coordinates", into: managedObjectContext)
        newCoordinate.setValue(member.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        newCoordinate.setValue(member.longitude, forKey: "longitude")
    }

    var newCoordinate = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Coordinates", into: managedObjectContext)
    newCoordinate.setValue(mapName, forKey: "mapName")
```

How could I separate them so I could refer to each chunk of data by mapName?

Answer (score 0):

There is a design misunderstanding. Your code creates `markersArray.count` `Coordinate`s (without name) and one additional `Coordinate` with a name but without `lat` and `long`.

There are (at least) two options:

- Add the map name to all coordinates in the loop and omit the final coordinate. Then get / identify the coordinates by map name.
- Create a new entity `Map` with attribute `name` and a one-to-many relationship to `Coordinate` and delete the `name` attribute in `Coordinate`.

Side-note: It's recommended to name entities in singular form (`Coordinate`)

Comment: Thank you. Why would I need to omit the final coordinate in option 1?

Comment: Once again you will have (e.g.) 5 coordinates with lat/long but without name and one coordinate with name but without lat/long. There is no relationship between them. In option 1 every coordinate will have lat/long **and** the name so the unrelated single coordinate is obsolete.